# Merging two TreeMaps while skipping the first entry in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, merge, treemap

I have two TreeMaps which I want to merge:

```
TreeMap<foo, bar> map1 = {key1=value1, key2=value2};
TreeMap<foo, bar> map2 = {key1=value6, key3=value3, key4=value4, key5=value5};
```

I want to merge these maps into a single one but I want to skip the first entry of second map, so I will have something like this:

```
TreeMap<foo, bar> result = {key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3, key4=value4, key5=value5};
```

However, I cannot call `map2.remove(map2.firstKey())` or even `map2.remove(key1)` because `equals` does not work fine on `foo`.

Is there a good way to do this?

(At the moment I am doing this which works fine, but I am not quite happy with it and I do not think it is the best way:

```
TreeMap<foo, bar> result = new TreeMap<>();
result.putAll(map1);

for (Map.Entry<foo, bar> entry : Iterables.skip(map2.entrySet(), 1) ) {
  result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

)

Comment: Your 2nd map has 2 keys named `key3`. is it a typo ?

Comment: `because equals does not work fine on foo` You should fix your equals method first. Otherwise all uses of TreeMap are futile because it may or may not do what you expect.

Comment: @Mritunjay thanks, fixed it

Comment: @Absurd-Mind thanks, but it is part of a big project which I have no access and it takes time to be fixed. Also, the only part of TreeMap that I am relying on is the fact that both maps have the same "first element" which TreeMap doesn't change the order so it is reliable.

Comment: `TreeMap` doesn't use `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tailMap`:

```
TreeMap<foo, bar> result = new TreeMap<>(map1);
result.putAll (map2.tailMap (map2.keySet().iterator().next(), false));
```

EDIT: You don't need to find the second key. You can run `tailMap` with inclusive == false, and pass to it the first key, which will be excluded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this would not work as `map2.tailMap(key2)` returns an empty TreeMap. I suppose `tailMap` uses `equals` to locate the entry which matches the input key. As `equals` returns false on all items, result of your code would be `map1`.

Comment: You made your code cleaner but still my issue exist. Since `foo.equals()` fails to compare, `map2.tailMap(anykey)` retruns empty TreeMap (it doesn't matter if `anykey` exist or not, `tailmap` can't find it).

Comment: @SalehPirouzi your problem can't be due to foo not implementing `equals` properly, because `TreeMap` never calls `equals()`. It only uses `compareTo()`. Your problem is caused by something other than `equals`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, I am not sure what is wrong with it. I assume it is something related to `equals` or `hashcode`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
TreeMap<Foo, Bar> result = new TreeMap<>(map2);
result.putAll(map1);
```

You said that the two maps always have the first element in common, and you seem to want to retain the first value from map1. Therefore, all you need to do is just a simple `putAll` of the entire map, so that the first value of map1 overwrites that of map2. No need for any additional code to skip the first entry of map2.

UPDATE: Following your comment, it looks as if Foo's `compareTo` method does not work correctly. You will therefore need to create your own custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and pass that to the [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) of all TreeMaps that you create.

You can use some code similar to this:

```
Comparator<Foo> myFooComparator = Comparator
        .comparing(Foo::getName)
        .thenComparingInt(Foo::getScore);

TreeMap<Foo, Bar> result = new TreeMap<>(myFooComparator);
result.putAll(map2);
result.putAll(map1);
```

Where `String Foo.getName()` and `int Foo.getScore()` are two public methods of Foo used as an example of what needs to be compared when comparing two Foo objects.

Comment: as I said, since something is wrong with the `equals` (and probably `hashcode` of foo), unfortunately this solution doesn't work and I end up with `{key1=value1, key2=value2, key1=value6, key3=value3, key4=value4, key5=value5}`

Comment: @SalehPirouzi TreeMap doesn't use `equals` at all. Nor does it use `hashCode`. It uses `compareTo`. If your `compareTo` method is not behaving correctly, you will need to construct TreeMaps with your own custom Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a suggestion with Streams (Java 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, String> map1 = new TreeMap<>();
    map1.put("key1", "value1");
    map1.put("key2", "value2");
    TreeMap<String, String> map2 = new TreeMap<>();
    map2.put("key1", "value6");
    map2.put("key3", "value3");
    map2.put("key4", "value4");
    map2.put("key5", "value5");
    String first = map2.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();
    Map<String, String> res =
            Stream.of(map1.entrySet(), map2.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(first)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) >= 0 ? a : b, TreeMap::new));
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

This prints:

```
{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3, key4=value4, key5=value5}
```

With this solution, the two input maps are not changed.